# How to Auto-increment XML elt value in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an xml file in my project repo which after checkout, I will like to auto increment the last value of the version number for every build. I am already accessing the version number using xmlslurper and storing this in a variable. I have something like this in my pipeline script and my xml file is just a single line script with 
      1.0.0.0  
and I will like auto increment the last digit for every build. NB: I do not want to use jenkins's build number. That would have been easy by just changing the last digit to $BUILD_NUMBER in my project repo.

```
@NonCPS

String getVersion(String path) 
{
  def version = new xmlSlurper().parse(new File(path))
  return version.toString()
}

node 
{


 stage ('checkout') {
 .........

 }

stage ('build) {
def pwd2=pwd()
def v=getVersion("${pwd2}/VersionNumber.xml")


sh ' dotnet publish path/to/project -p:Fileversion=$v '

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no plugin for this, so I guess you can just go with groovy. If you don't like the build number, try this

```
def test = "1.1.1.1"
def splitted = test.split('\\.')
splitted[3] = (((splitted[3] as BigDecimal) + 1) as String)
def testInc = splitted.join('.')
print(testInc)
```

For the build number approach I would suggest to keep the whole version in jenkinsfile, should be as simple as:

```
def version = "1.0.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. This for sure increased by one. How can I increase then for every build? because this increases just for the current build.When I execute the pipeline again, i get same number like the previously executed build

Comment: Solutions I've seen would commit the version changed back to source control. But that's really for release builds that are not triggered by code changes. Modern CI/CD approach would say - use the build number ;)

Comment: my idea was to use this approach to control how large numbers can get because the build number goes significantly high which is not supported in our case. by using this customized xml file, i am able to reset the number back to zero when required. I appreciate your contribution.

Comment: glad I could help. Thanks for accepting the answer.

Comment: One last thing, how can use the build number then in the last digit?

Comment: updated my answer, that's one of the possible approaches, other could be just assigning the env.BUILD_NUMBER to the third element of the splitted.

Comment: Assigning splitted[3] = ${BUILD_NUMBER} throws an exception. don't know what is the problem.Sorry for bugging but I am new to this. thanks for your time :)

Comment: For this you can do splitted[3] = env.BUILD_NUMBER